# why the table margins go wrong when it is dir="rtl"?

Tags: html, css, firefox

when I change the page direction to `rtl` the table margins is go incorrect,as in this picture
[image]

but when I **only** remove the `dir` attribute from the page every thing is go correct , as in 
[image]

#### CSS

```
table,td,tr {
    border: 2px solid black;
    padding:0px;
}
```

#### HTML

```
<body>
    <table>
        <tr> <td></td><td></td> </tr>
        <tr> <td></td><td></td> </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

*this happens in firefox but on chrome the table is correct on both directions!*

how to solve this issue?

#### EDIT:

I just reported a new bug to Bugzilla today(after 3 years from the question :D), here is the link https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1580346

Comment: Interesting... it also happens with the CSS `direction:rtl` property.

Comment: `This happens in firefox but on chrome the table is correct on both directions!` - Then that is most likely a bug and should be reported to the Firefox bug tracker.

Comment: I've tested, and it only started to go wrong in Firefox v41. Older versions are OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comments say, it IS a bug.

However.

In reality there is no need to give `border` properties to `tr` elements. In fact, there's hardly any need to give any properties to `tr` elements whatsoever, except in very specialised situations.
So, you can remove the `,tr` from the CSS selector.
If you do, nothing will change for the worse - the table will still look the same in LTR mode. But it will also look OK in RTL mode. This, therefore, is the solution to your problem.

```css
table,td {
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<body dir="rtl">
  <table>
    <tr> <td>test</td><td>test</td> </tr>
    <tr> <td>test</td><td>test</td> </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

Comment: I just reported a [bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1580346) today