# Table tr shadow not works on Chrome - Firefox is fine

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome

I want to set shadow for TR - on Firefox works fine but on Chrome not working.
`box-shadow` for TD works on every browsers.
[image]
I'm using Bootstrap with DataTables so when I set `display: block;` for TR, I getting:
[image]

Here is CSS:

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 0 #000;
   -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 0 #000;
        box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 0 #000;
```

Comment: Looks like a reasonable question, but we are going to need to see your source http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Please add your code.

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu I added code into my post.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Box Shadow on table row not appearing on certain browsers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10874985/box-shadow-on-table-row-not-appearing-on-certain-browsers)

Comment: You shouldn't really rely on setting _any_ styles on `tr`s. Table rows are not supposed to have styles of themselves, and many, many properties cause different behaviours between browsers. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10514900/table-row-background-image), [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38816104/why-the-table-margins-go-wrong-when-it-is-dir-rtl) etc.