# Firefox is not complying with RFC6265 regarding processing the path attribute of cookies

Tags: php, google-chrome, firefox, cookies, rfc6265

I was writing a PHP class for dealing with/parsing the `Cookie` and `Set-Cookie` HTTP headers to use it in my custom user-agents (crawlers, scrapers, bots, ..etc), and while testing it I found that it behaves different than Firefox in the way they process the `Path` attribute in the `Set-Cookie` header. I returned back to [RFC 6265](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-5.1.4) and I was right

###How to reproduce?
In any PHP file set this line and request it

```
<?php
header("set-cookie: foo=1; path=/bar/", true);
exit;
```

Now request `/bar` with Firefox, you will see that Firefox is sending the cookie, while it should only send to `/bar/` or longer path according to the specifications !!

###What are the specifications ?

I will quote the related part from [RFC 6265 5.1.4 Paths and Path-Match](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-5.1.4)

> A request-path path-matches a given cookie-path if at least one of the following conditions holds:
>
> o  The cookie-path and the request-path are identical.
>
> o  The cookie-path is a prefix of the request-path, and the last
> character of the cookie-path is %x2F ("/").
>
> o  The cookie-path is a prefix of the request-path, and the first
> character of the request-path that is not included in the cookie-
> path is a %x2F ("/") character.

In this case the request-path `/bar` and the cookie-path `/bar/` do not path-match

###What about Google Chrome ?

Google Chrome does **NOT** send the cookie to `/bar`

#### My Question

> Who is right ? Chrome ? or Firefox ?

###Extra Details:

I tested on Firefox 66.0.4 on Linux and Chrome Version 76.0.3809.132 Linux

This is the related function I use in my class

```
public static function isPathMatch(string $requestPath, string $cookiePath)
{
    if ($requestPath === $cookiePath) return true;
    if (strpos($requestPath, $cookiePath) !== 0) return false;
    if (substr($cookiePath, strlen($cookiePath) - 1, 1) === "/") return true;
    if (substr($requestPath, strlen($cookiePath), 1) === "/") return true;
    return false;
}
```

This is the second issue I [find](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38816104/5407848) for Firefox, however it still my favorite browser :)

Thanks for @fendall on the comment about the RFC, I tracked the RFCs that are related to this issue

- February 1997 [RFC 2109](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2109) HISTORIC. Obsoleted by
- October 2000 [RFC 2965](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2965) HISTORIC. Obsoleted by
- April 2011 [RFC 6265](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265) PROPOSED STANDARD, if approved will be Obsoleted by
- August 2017 [draft-ietf-httpbis-rfc6265bis-02](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-rfc6265bis-02) Internet-Draft

**The [MDN Set-Cookie Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie#Specifications) used the specifications of both [RFC 6265](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-5.1.4) and [draft-ietf-httpbis-rfc6265bis-02](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-rfc6265bis-02#section-5.1.4)** and both specifications are almost the same in the "Paths and Path-Match" section. (*the part I quoted in the question*)

I reported a bug to Bugzilla https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1579552

Comment: An RFC is not necessarily part of internet standards. By search on IETF, you'll see that this RFC you refer to is a proposed standard: https://www.rfc-editor.org/search/rfc_search_detail.php?rfc=6265&pubstatus%5B%5D=Any&pub_date_type=any

Comment: @fendall Where would one go to look for what the current accepted internet standards are in this case? I found another RFC (https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2109.txt) that states explicitly that the path: *"Defaults to the path of the request URL that generated the Set-Cookie response, up to, but not including, the right-most /."*, which would seem to indicate that Firefox is actually correct, not Chrome.

Comment: @Mike No, this is the "default path", the user-agent should use it in case the cookie `Path` attribute is empty or not starts with `/`

Comment: @fendall hmmm, thanks for this, so what is the current applied standard I should refer to if I want to create a user-agent ?

Comment: @Accountantم Oh, you're right.

Comment: @Accountantم@Mike I found a couple links that might help: (https://www.rfc-editor.org/retrieve/), (https://www.rfc-editor.org/standards#IS)

Comment: @Accountantم If you think about it though, the **default** path explicitly excludes the right-most /, so if you set a cookie for the request URL `/bar/`, the cookie's path will default to `/bar` with no trailing slash, which **may** indicate one of two things; that when manually setting the cookie path to `/bar/` the browser should remove the trailing slash like it does in the default case, or that these URLs can be considered to be equal.

Comment: @Mike *"the browser should remove the trailing slash like it does in the default case"*... yes I understand what you mean, but if the server set the `path` attribute in the cookie and it was starting with `/` the browser will use it as the cookie path instead of the default one, check in FF and chrome cookies store you will find many cookies paths end with `/` . But yeah as you said `/bar/` and `/bar` should be considered equal.

Comment: @fendall thanks for the links, I tracked the RFCs as shown in the edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Chrome was right, as commented by [ehsan akhgari](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1579552#ct-2) in the bug report

> Yes, our [path matching algorithm](https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/rev/250f5cc9fb8bdcbb6b23d2a06acfd48addb2f99b/netwerk/cookie/nsCookieService.cpp#2955) is completely different than the spec. Comparing to [Chrome's](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/net/cookies/canonical_cookie.cc?l=375&rcl=b24c550e3a82a235cb131bffae13196579ee4093) they seeming to be following the spec pretty closely.

... and they changed the source code of Firefox and fix it https://phabricator.services.mozilla.com/D45427